# iptables firewall rules not allowing ssh from lan to DMZ

Tags: iptables

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www reject-with tcp-reset 
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:telnet reject-with tcp-reset 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
logdrop    icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
logdrop    igmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:5060 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
logaccept  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
logdrop    0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     0    --  192.168.0.0/24       192.168.2.0/24      reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  choister             192.168.2.142       tcp dpt:ssh state NEW 
REJECT     0    --  192.168.0.0/24       192.168.3.0/24      reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
ACCEPT     gre  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            tcp dpt:1723 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
lan2wan    0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
logaccept  tcp  --  anywhere             choister            tcp dpt:www 
TRIGGER    0    --  anywhere             anywhere            TRIGGER type:in match:0 relate:0 
trigger_out  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
logaccept  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
logdrop    0    --  anywhere             anywhere
```

The ssh server I'm trying to connect to is in the DMZ(192.168.0.145). It's mainly used as a web server. I need access to it from my room 192.168.2.142. I don't get why ssh can't forward onto the 192.168.2.0 subnet? I'm sure it's the reject rule that causing this because it works without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant for this rule:
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  choister             192.168.2.142       tcp dpt:ssh
to have 2.142 as the source not the destination...

Comment: but the forwarding chain  is set to block any communication from the DMZ hence when i connect to ssh it's not allowed to establish the connection to the lan.  I don't want the dmz being able to establish connections to the lan otherwise wants the point in the DMZ. Also I have tried it anyway since am an amateur but no doesn't work.

Comment: your allow rule just needs to be first

Comment: you're the man. I never doubted you're the one to help me.